# Compartilhar código (React ou Vue) entre mais de um projeto

Tags: react, git, vue.js

Vamos dizer que eu tenho a aplicação web em React ou Vue. Parte do código eu vou reutilizar para vários clientes, cerca de 70%. Os outros 30% seriam mudanças de layout e algum COMPONENTE extra que cada cliente necessite.

Existem alguma forma controlar isso? Fazer esse 70% de código virar um plugin, ou criar uma tarefa do Gulp para ficar copiando os arquivos iguais de um projeto para outro?

Eu acho que o ideal era ter um repositório só com esses 70%, e outros repositórios para cada personalização de cliente.

Como vocês me sugerem fazer isso? Alguém já fez?

Answer (score 0):

Então, eu tive um caso semelhante a isto uma vez. Em uma empresa que trabalhei, nós havíamos criado devido a necessidade nossa própria biblioteca de componentes, e conforme novos projetos foram surgindo, tínhamos que copiar todos os componentes.
Para melhorar a manutenção, atualização desses componentes, e não ter que realizar sempre essa cópia manual, optamos por fazer o seguinte:

1. Selecionar todos os componentes que serão reutilizáveis entre os projetos;
2. Refatorar todos os componentes selecionados para que eles não  tenham nenhuma lógica/regra de negócio dentro deles;
3. Criar um projeto/repositório separado para eles;
4. Criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento para este novo repositório, neste caso usamos Storybook (testes visuais, desenvolvimento e documentação), testes unitários com Jest, e testes de regressão com Pupeteer/Jest;
5. Com os componentes prontos e testados, criamos um script para realizar sua instalação, para instalação desta nova biblioteca de componentes, no estilo Vuetify/Buefy;
6. Como era um cliente e componentes privados, subimos em um servidor com [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus/repository-pro), mas se não precisasse ser privado, poderia subir no npm;
7. Apagamos todos os componentes que foram copiados nos projetos;
8. Instalamos essa nova biblioteca de componentes em todos os projetos;

Agora quando precisamos adicionar um novo componente, feature nova, ou alteração, alteramos na biblioteca (se é algo reutilizável), e subimos uma nova versão, depois só atualizar os projetos que estão utilizando ela.

Espero ter ajudado.